# Complex, Holomorphic connection, and Symplectic — a not-so-Kähler manifold?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, gauge-theory, complex-numbers

While studying mathematical physics, I wondered whether if there is a mathematical theory for a manifold that

- has a complex structure [almost complex structure $J^\mu{}_\nu$ with vanishing Nijenhuis tensor $N^\lambda{}_{\mu\nu}=0$ (or $\bar{\partial}^2=0$) so that the complex coordinates $x^\mu=(z^i,\bar{z}^{\bar{i}})$ are well-defined such that different coordinate patches agree with the notion of holomorphy (especially on “holomorphic differential forms”)],
- has a (anti-)holomorphic connection $\Gamma^i{}_j=\Gamma^i{}_{jk}(z) dz^j$, $\bar{\Gamma}^{\bar{i}}{}_{\bar{j}} = \bar{\Gamma}^{\bar{i}}{}_{\bar{j}\bar{k}}(\bar{z}) d\bar{z}^{\bar{j}}$ ​[and, in turn, (anti-)holomorphic curvature $R^i{}_j(z) = \partial\Gamma^i{}_j(z) + \Gamma^i{}_k(z)\wedge\Gamma^k{}_j(z)$, $\bar{R}^\bar{i}{}_\bar{j}(\bar{z}) = \bar{\partial}\bar{\Gamma}^\bar{i}{}_\bar{j}(\bar{z}) + \Gamma^\bar{i}{}_\bar{k}(\bar{z})\wedge\Gamma^\bar{k}{}_\bar{j}(\bar{z})$],
- and, most importantly, admits a symplectic form $\omega$, which will be a “real” two-form because I want the action and the symplectic potential to be real. Let's say $\omega$ is compatible with the (anti-)holomorphic connection.

Such a manifold will not be Kähler.
What I am having in mind is that terms like $\frac{1}{2} \alpha_i{}^j(z,\bar{z}) R^i{}_j(z) = \frac{1}{4} \alpha_i{}^j(z,\bar{z}) R^i{}_{jkl}(z) dz^k\wedge dz^l$ entering in $\omega$.
Note that in Kähler manifolds the symplectic form takes the form $\omega = ig_{i\bar{j}}(z,\bar{z}) dz^i\wedge d\bar{z}^{\bar{j}}$.
(I am not assuming a hermitian metric $g_{i\bar{j}}(z,\bar{z})$ to be necessarily exist.)

The motivation of this question was that in Kähler manifolds it seems that the connection is not “holomorphic.”
Of course, components with mixed indices such as $\Gamma^i{}_{j\bar{k}}$ or $\Gamma^{\bar{i}}{}_{jk}$ vanish.
But, from the expression for the Riemann and Ricci tensors in Kähler manifolds, I suppose that the “holomorphic” connection is not really holomorphic at all, as $\bar{\partial}_{\bar{k}}\Gamma^i{}_{lj}$ does not vanish: $\Gamma^i{}_{jk}(z,\bar{z})$.
In turn, the non-vanishing components of the Riemann tensor have index structure $R^i{}_{j\bar{k}l}$ and $R^{\bar{i}}{}_{\bar{j}k\bar{l}}$.
What I want is the “truly” holomorphic connection and curvature: $\Gamma^i{}_{jk}(z)$ and $\bar{\Gamma}^{\bar{i}}{}_{\bar{j}\bar{k}}(\bar{z})$ (in the differential form language, $\bar{\partial}\Gamma^i{}_j$ = 0).

Is there a name for such a manifold? Is such a manifold possible? Can we develop a theory for it? Thanks!

[Edit: I added the compatibility condition for the symplectic form. To explain a bit more about my situation—I am trying to "design" a speculative theory without knowing the path to the final answer. So, feel free to make any modifications or refinements to the conditions I have presented, if doing so makes the resulting geometry consistent and plausible. The most important ones are the holomorphy of connections and the existence of (real) symplectic structure. I am not sure whether I can ask this kind of "open" question here, though...]

Comment: From your bullet points it seems that the symplectic structure is not related to the rest.  For an example take a complex vector space with the flat connection.

Comment: Is the connection torsionfree or symplectic?

Comment: Dear MBN and Qmechanic, thanks for pointing out that. Let's say the connection is compatible with the symplectic structure. (I am speculating a geometric construction for a physical system in a real Ricci-flat Riemannian manifold that seems to enjoy a complex structure on the complexified tangent spaces. Unfortunately, what conditions I should demand such a theory is not entirely crystal-clear yet. I think I should add more details to my question as things get more clear to me.)